# Angular reactive form value don't filled by third-party service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a reactive address form and third-party service for address lookups *(Loqate in my case, and this service injected by injecting script in HTML)*.

Few of fields can be autocompleted/autofilled by the service *(like in the GIF below)*. And few of fields are required. When user choose one of suggested address - form filled in UI (HTML), but not in Angular form in the component.

How I can detect changes by third-party service and fill form value?

For example form:

```js
this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  Country: ['', Validators.required],
  OrderShippingAddressLine1: ['', Validators.required],
  OrderShippingAddressLine2: [''],
  OrderShippingAddressPostcode: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

A minimal example of components, but unfortunately without the service on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auyzjh).

[image]

Comment: Form Input controls are created in Angular right?

Comment: Please add some more sample code to work with. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I created an example of my components, but unfortunately, I can't integrate service (because it's paid a service) - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auyzjh

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya yes, form controls created in Angular

Comment: @ArtOlshansky, your StackBlitz doesn't have the implementation of this "*thing*" that you're using. I'd urge you to subscribe to the `valueChanges` on the form to check if chainging the value on the Post code field actually changes the value of the Address Line 1 field.

Comment: @SiddAjmera yeah, I understand, but as I wrote, I can't implement it in stackblitz. In subscription to `valueChanges` I don't receive changes in the field values after selecting one of the suggested addresses *(as I wrote in question)*. Controls values don't changed. I suppose the third-party service changes only html and Angular doesn't see it

Comment: This third party service is a real question mark here. Without knowing that, it won't really be possible to understand what's the issue here. It could have something to do with the way you're setting the relevant values once you get the response from this service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Loqate *(as I do)*, you need to know about `pca` object in you `window` object.

Loqate support sent me that piece of code for triggering change event

```js
pca.on("data", function(source, key, address, variations) {
  if (source === "address") {
    for (var i = 0; i < pca.platform.productList[key].PLATFORM_CAPTUREPLUS.bindings[0].fields.length; i++) {
      var pcaField = document.getElementById(pca.platform.productList[key].PLATFORM_CAPTUREPLUS.bindings[0].fields[i].element);
      if (pcaField) {
        pca.fire(pcaField, "change");
      };
    };
  };
});
```

Few more strings of code for change/patch form controls value and `updateValueAndValidity`, and that works

Answer (score 1):

You can use detectChanges() in built angular function to detect changes automatically.You can get more information on this  [link](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef). If you still face issue share code and angular version.